# IProgressMonitor is not able to get monitor.isCanceled() method call

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, e4

Good afternoon and hope you are doing great :)

I have method in which I have written new IRunnableWithProgress and I am getting progress bar and all process updates properly no issue at all.

My issue is I can see cancel button on progress bar dailog but after clicking on it nothing is happening. In short code inside if(monitor.isCanceled()){ sysout("Heloooooooooo") } is not executing at all.

please have a look at code sample :

```
public void runMappers(final EObject profile, final EObject list, final Notification notification) {
    this.notification = notification;
    getBroker().stopNotification();
    final ProgressMonitorDialog pmd = new ProgressMonitorDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell());
    IRunnableWithProgress rwp = new IRunnableWithProgress() {
        @Override
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InterruptedException {
            if (mappers.get(profile) != null) {
                int workload = mappers.get(profile).size();
                monitor.beginTask("Loading DG list configurations", workload);
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ProfileTo(.*?)ViewMapper");
                for (final ProfileToDgListViewMapper mapper : mappers.get(profile)) {
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mapper.toString());
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        monitor.subTask("Loading DG list configuration section " + (matcher.group(1)));
                    }
                    mapper.mapProfile(profile, list, notification);
                    monitor.worked(1);
                    if(monitor.isCanceled()){
                        System.out.println("Heloooooooooo");
                        monitor.done();
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        monitor.done();
        }
    };
    try {
        pmd.run(false, true, rwp);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    getBroker().continueNotification();
}
```

I tried so many things also some stackoverflow answers, suggesting to perform it with Jobs, But i am not sure how can i call my custome method(with some attributes) in the Job.
Please let me know best suggestion
Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Probably you should be specifying `true` for the `pmd.run` first parameter (`fork`)

Comment: Hi really thanks for your quick response, now it is getting called. But after clicking on cancel first I am getting " ConcurrentModificationException " & then it is completing the  process it is not actually getting canceled.

org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.util.ConcurrentModificationException)

Comment: You should not be calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` just throw an InterruptedException. We would have to see a stack trace for any other errors.